# Radial eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator in spherical coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to find solutions for the following ODE (which was derived trying to find the fundamental solution of the PDE $\Delta u+cu=0$ where $c > 0$ see below for the approach)

The ODE is

$v''(r)+\frac{2}{r} v'(r)+cv(r)=0$

I am not really sure how to solve this. I haven't done a computational ODE course, and I did look around but couldn't find any resource which tells a way to approach such problems clearly. Any help or at least a hint or a resource would be appreciated.

As for solving the PDE, I was looking for radial solutions and thats how I arrived at the ODE. (Mainly following the Laplace Equation method from Evans). Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this approach too

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us set $w(r) = r v(r)$. Using the product rule, we have the relationships
$$
w'(r) = v(r) + r v'(r)
$$
and
$$
w''(r) = 2 v'(r) + r v''(r) .
$$
Thus, the differential equation rewrites as a linear equation with constant coefficients
$$
w''(r) + c w(r) = 0 \, ,
$$
whose solutions are $w(r) = A\cos(r\sqrt{c}) + B\sin(r\sqrt{c})$. Division by $r$ then provides $v(r)$.

Comment: I guess you wrote the transform the other way around... If we use w = r*v, then we have w''+cw=0.

Comment: @QiuyeJia You are correct; thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, so I'm likely to miss something. But the usual thing would be to assume that $v(r) $ is analytic, substitute the series into your equation balance the indices, and get a recursion for the coefficients of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in the original form
$$-r^{-2} \partial_r(r^2\partial_r v(r)) = k^2\  v(r) $$
Its a trivial equation for $r^2 v(r)$
$$ \partial_r(r^2\partial_r v(r)) = k^2 (r^2\ v(r)) $$

Works generally for the radial operator in n dimensions with
$$-\Delta_r =- r^{-n+1} \partial_r (r^{n-1}\ \partial_r v(r)) = k^2\  v(r) $$